# Something is eating up all my storage space and I don't know what it is

Tags: rooting, 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, storage

I'm using a 2014 Moto X, 32GB. Recently I've noticed very low free disk space and I'm not sure what is causing it. When I plug in the phone to my PC Windows Explorer shows 556MB free of 24.7GB at the time I'm posting this. But when I go into the phone's storage (in windows), highlight all the files and folders, then get the properties it shows that everything totals up to 2.79GB. Something's not right, the numbers just don't add up. I've also used Solid Explorer to try and figure out where this is coming from, but the numbers there also don't add up. It is showing 1.03GB free on internal memory, but when I look at the list of folders sorted by size (screenshots below) it doesn't add up.

Any ideas how I can figure out what files are taking up all this space on my phone? I can't even seem to find them.

Thanks!

[image: Screenshot of Solid Explorer's Info] [image: The biggest folders Solid Explorer is showing] [image: Android System's storage summary]
<sup>Screenshots of: Solid Explorer's Info / biggest folders / Android System's storage summary (click images to enlarge)</sup>